# document.writeln not working as expected

Tags: javascript

With the following line of code:

```
document.writeln("blahblahblah")
```

I expect the content to be placed on its own line, but instead the content is inserted, but with no new line. Only a space.

Is it expected?

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to make questions looking better. I gave you 1 up vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new line will be displayed only inside code output tags (pre, code etc.). In other cases browser will convert it into space.